# Typeset \part in document without affecting head, ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, fancyhdr, parts

Is there a way to influence typesetting of \part{} within the document, but without at the same time affecting it in ToC and the page headings? I have several different parts – in my minimal example "Introduction", "Appendix" – and several related ones – in my minimal example "Example 1, 2". Since I want the prefix "Example n" in some but not all part headings simply redefining part is not an option.

In the related parts I want a line break after the bit that stays the same (Example n) only in the heading, in ToC and head I want it on the same line:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\part}[display]{}{}{1em}{\sffamily\huge}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{}{1em}{\sffamily\large}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead[L]{\textit{\textrm{\footnotesize{\rightmark}}}}    

\renewcommand{\partmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Introduction}
    Bla \newpage Bla Bla 

\part{Example 1:\\Foo}
    Bla \newpage Bla Bla 

\part{Example 2:\\Bar}
    Bla \newpage Bla Bla 

\part{Appendix}
    Bla \newpage Bla Bla 

\end{document}
```

**E D I T** (after @RicoRally's very good answer came in): Another option for solving this problem is using `titlesec` with two options, one solving the `newline`-issue, the other the numbering: `\usepackage[newlinetospace, newparttoc]{titlesec}`. This solution was provided by @Bernard at this follow up question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211026#answer-211046

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force parts not to be displayed in the table of contents.
This can be done suppressing the command `\l@part`.

You could add this in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@part[2]{}
\makeatother
```

This is quite a rough way to deal with LaTeX, but it works.
Your document could be:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@part[2]{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Introduction}
    \chapter{Bla} \newpage Bla Bla 

\part{Example 1:\\Foo}
    Bla \newpage Bla Bla 

\part{Example 2:\\Bar}
    \chapter{Bla} \newpage Bla Bla 

\part{Appendix}
    Bla \newpage Bla Bla 

\end{document}
```

In this way only other objects are displayed in the contents.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Seul I finally understood the question properly.

For that it's enough to use the optional argument of `\part`. It's used when we want to specify a different title in the head and in the table of contents (they will be the same).

In your case my previous code will become:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\part}[display]{}{}{1em}{\sffamily\huge}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{}{1em}{\sffamily\large}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead[L]{\textit{\textrm{\footnotesize{\rightmark}}}}    

\renewcommand{\partmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Introduction}
    Bla \newpage Bla Bla 

\part[Example 1: Foo]{Example 1:\\Foo}
    Bla \newpage Bla Bla 

\part[Example 2: Bar]{Example 2:\\Bar}
    Bla \newpage Bla Bla 

\part{Appendix}
    Bla \newpage Bla Bla 

\end{document}
```

Comment: With `hyperref` this might not work, but it's not difficult to find a similar workaround in that case.

Comment: Thanks RicoRally for taking the time to answer. However, I'm not sure whether it gets clear enough from my question what I want to do: 1) have \part as a heading including optional line break 2) keep part in ToC on a single line 3) keep \part in document head on a single line.

Comment: @Seul thank you for being clear, I edited the answer already.

Comment: Thanks a lot for coming back and solving it! The solution works perfectly on the example I posted, however... there's something I didn't tell you: in my real document I use the starred variant of part because I want to avoid the leading number in ToC ("Example 1: Foo" rather than "2 Example 1: Foo"), and for the life of me I could not get titletoc to drop that number for part. But that is a different question altogether. Thanks again!

Comment: Asked the new question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211026/remove-leading-part-number-in-toc-with-titletoc