# remove leading "part" number in toc with titletoc

Tags: table-of-contents, parts, titletoc

Is there a way to display part names, but not numbers in ToC with `titletoc`?

simply removing `\thecontentslabel` seems easy enough for chapter, section etc, but not part.

**Background:** I used the starred variant (`\part*{foo}`) but as I also would like some `parts` to have a line break in the document and be on the same line in ToC and page header, I would need the optional argument, which doesn't work with the starred variant (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210976/typeset-part-in-document-without-affecting-head-toc) for the reasons).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\part}[display]{}{}{1em}{\sffamily\huge}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{part}[0em]
    {\vspace{2em}\large\bfseries\sffamily}
    {}{}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Introduction}
    Bla

\part[Example 1: Foo]{Example 1:\\Foo}
    Bla

\part[Example 2: Bar]{Example 2:\\Bar}
    Bla

\part{Appendix}
    Bla

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: in creating the example I realised the problem arises only if I use both titlesec and titletoc, when I remove titlesec, there are no leading numbers for part in the toc.

Comment: Seul: KOMA script (`scrbook`) and `titlesec` do not really match together! You should drop one of them

Comment: oops. would you have a suggestions which one best to drop? and replace with what? I am in the final stages of my PhD, so I am a bit reluctant to change major variables here...

Comment: another question: `KOMA` and `titletoc` are fine?

Comment: Seul: I am no KOMA expert (User Johannes_B knows the details about KOMA -- I gave him a notice about your question) and regarding: `KOMA` and `titletoc`... no, I would not combine them

Comment: bad news at this stage in my thesis. I just tried replacing KOMA and get loads of errors for customisations I did, so maybe I just leave it as it is for now and use a proper combination for my next PhD. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I will try to provide a solution. `\part*{}` can be replaced by `\addpart{}` or something like this, which provides for optional arguments instead which `\part*{}` can't... see my 'solution'

Comment: thanks, I appreciate it. will try it out later in my real document.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18499/discussion-between-seul-and-christian-hupfer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use the starred version if you want *no*  part label to appear in the toc. With the `newlinetospace` option, it is needless to use the optional argument to remove a line break in titles: it is automatically converted to a horizontal space in table of contents and headers.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[newlinetospace, newparttoc]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\part}[display]{}{}{1em}{\sffamily\huge}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{part}[0em]
    {\vspace{2em}\large\bfseries\sffamily\relax}
    {\contentslabel[\relax]{0em}}{}{\hfill\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Introduction}
    Bla

\part{Example 1:\\Foo}%
    Bla

\part{Example 2:\\Bar}%[
    Bla

\part{Appendix}
    Bla

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works really well and feels less of a hack. Do I understand correctly that `newparttoc`-option is responsible for removing the part-number in the ToC? In the titlesec-documentation it says the options is changing its use from a »non standard way« and I do not quite get what that means (p8).

Comment: I don't really understand either. I think (not sure) some changes made to part formatting are unefficient without this option. I know I should experiment to understand what's behind all this, but never had time to do it…

Comment: but it _is_ the option responsible for suppressing the leading numbers, right?

Comment: also, I feel that your answer would add valuable information to the first question I asked regarding this problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210976/typeset-part-in-document-without-affecting-head-toc not sure how the proper way would be: should I ask you to paste it there again? should I do it? should I comment there with a link to this answer here?

Comment: @Seul: The pure KOMA solution is no hack ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: sorry, Christian, I did not mean to offend you. When you spoke of a 'solution' (rather than a solution), I concluded it had to be some sort of a hack. Now I find it even harder as to which answer I should pick, as they both work well and do what they should. But you are both reputation-wealthy, so maybe it does not matter that much.

Comment: @Seul: I don't feel offended, that's why I wrote ';-)' in the comment ... I just wanted to state that it's no hack but a pure, clean solution without much ado (and to-do)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer very good then, thanks again!

Comment: @Seul: The `newparttoc` option is responsible for the fact that, among the arguments to `\titlecontents{\part}` , `\contentslabel[\relax]{0em}` works. I think it says to latex something like ‘Let me manage the formatting of parts in toc.’

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}

%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\titleformat{\part}[display]{}{}{1em}{\sffamily\huge}

%\usepackage{titletoc}
%\titlecontents{part}[0em]
%    {\vspace{2em}\large\bfseries\sffamily}
%    {}{}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Introduction}
    Bla

\addpart[Example 1: Foo]{Example 1:\\Foo}
    Bla

\addpart[Example 2: Bar]{Example 2:\\Bar}
    Bla

\part{Appendix}
    Bla

\end{document}
```

[image]